# How to loop through array JSONATA

Tags: json, node-red, jsonata

Here is my array:

```json
{
"tocontrol": [{"name": "john"},{"name": "doe"}]
}
```

I'm expecting below output:

```json
{
  "method": "OR",
  "match": [
    {
      "match": {
        "name": "jhon"
      }
    },
    {
      "match": {
        "name": "doe"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried $join function but not getting the expected result.

Can someone help me to get expected output?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In order to achieve the desired result, you need to use a `.` (map) expression: https://docs.jsonata.org/path-operators#-map

This is what the finished result looks like:

```
{
    "method": "OR",
    "match": tocontrol.{
        "name": name
    }
}
```

Link to JSONata exerciser: https://try.jsonata.org/NuR_JI3ua

[image: A screenshot of JSONata exerciser]

---

By the way, I’ve built this solution in 2 minutes by using the [Mappings tool](https://www.stedi.com/products/mappings) that my team is building at [Stedi](https://stedi.com).

[image: A screenshot of Stedi's Mapping tool]